# Blazor Webassembly dont show icon when install in windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

When i install Blazor Webassembly to Desktop, the icon didn't show up in desktop.

In Browser Tab, it work. The Icon Shows. In Android the icon works too. But in Windows Desktop the icon didnt show.

I Already put it in manifest.json and index.html

In manifest.json :

```
"icons": [
    {
      "src": "File/Logo1.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ]
```

in index.html :

```
<link href="File/Logo1.png" rel="icon" />
```

it works in chrome browser tab and android. but not in windows. Can someone help me with these problem